# Symfony 3 : The annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

When I put my project into production , I get that error :

The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\type" in property  does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

I don't understand the reason why, because when I work locally, everything is ok.

Here's my code :

```
namespace EC\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use EC\ToolsBundle\StrTools\StrTools; 

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EC\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="nb_recette", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true, "default" = 0})
 * @Assert\type(type="integer")
 */
    private $nb_recette = 0;

//...
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change this:

```
* @Assert\type(type="integer")
```

to this:

```
* @Assert\Type(type="integer")
```

Annotations are case sensitive for this reason you retrieve an error

Comment: Glad to help you! @EmmCall

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, it should be `@Assert\Type`

Symfony implements PSR-4 for autoloading so if you take a look [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) you will notice that

> All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.